# How do I prevent `hadoop fs rmr <uri>` from creating $folder$ files?

Tags: hadoop

We're using Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce to perform some large file processing jobs. As a part of our workflow, we occasionally need to remove files from S3 that may already exist. We do so using the hadoop fs interface, like this:

```
hadoop fs -rmr s3://mybucket/a/b/myfile.log
```

This removes the file from S3 appropriately, but in it's place leaves an empty file named "s3://mybucket/a/b_$folder$". As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737752/how-do-you-deal-with-empty-or-missing-input-files-in-apache-pig), Hadoop's Pig is unable to handle these files, so later steps in the workflow can choke on this file.

(Note, it doesn't seem to matter whether we use `-rmr` or `-rm` or whether we use `s3://` or `s3n://` as the scheme: all of these exhibit the described behavior.)

How do I use the `hadoop fs` interface to remove files from S3 and be sure not to leave these troublesome files behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out if it's possible to use the hadoop fs interface in this way. However, the s3cmd interface does the right thing (but only for one key at a time):

```
s3cmd del s3://mybucket/a/b/myfile.log
```

This requires configuring a ~/.s3cfg file with your AWS credentials first. `s3cmd --configure` will interactively help you create this file.

Answer (score 0):

It is how the S3 suppot is implemented in Hadoop, see this: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/NativeS3FileSystem.html.

So use s3cmd.