# How does Pig use Hadoop Globs in a 'load' statement?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

As I've [noted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737752/how-do-you-deal-with-empty-or-missing-input-files-in-apache-pig), Pig doesn't cope well with empty (0-byte) files. Unfortunately, there are lots of ways that these files can be created (even [within Hadoop utilitities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749272/how-do-i-prevent-hadoop-fs-rmr-uri-from-creating-folder-files)).

I thought that I could work around this problem by explicitly loading only files that match a given naming convention in the [LOAD statement](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.6.0/piglatin_ref2.html#LOAD) using [Hadoop's glob syntax](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#globStatus%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%29). Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, as even when I use a glob to filter down to known-good input files, I still run into the 0-byte failure [mentioned earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737752/how-do-you-deal-with-empty-or-missing-input-files-in-apache-pig).

Here's an example: Assume I have the following files in S3:

- mybucket/a/b/ (0 bytes)
- mybucket/a/b/myfile.log (>0 bytes)
- mybucket/a/b/yourfile.log (>0 bytes)

If I use a LOAD statement like this in my pig script:

```
myData = load 's3://mybucket/a/b/*.log as ( ... )
```

I would expect that Pig would not choke on the 0-byte file, but it still does. Is there a trick to getting Pig to actually only look at files that match the expected glob pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly ugly solution, but globs that don't rely on the `*` wildcard syntax appear to work. So, in our workflow (before calling our pig script), we list all of the files below the prefix we're interested, and then create a specific glob that consists of only the paths we're interested in.

For example, in the example above, we list "mybucket/a":

```
hadoop fs -lsr s3://mybucket/a
```

Which returns a list of files, plus other metadata. We can then create the glob from that data:

```
myData = load 's3://mybucket/a/b{/myfile.log,/yourfile.log}' as ( ... )
```

This requires a bit more front-end work, but allows us to specifically target files we're interested and avoid 0-byte files.

**Update:** Unfortunately, I've found that this solution fails when the glob pattern gets long; Pig ends up throwing an exception "Unable to create input slice".